# Lightning web component is not visible in lighting home or app page

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

I am trying to upload a custom component on the community site page, but it's not visible on the community site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give it a try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Remember to use the format code button (`{}`) in the editor to have your code properly appear.